# How can I scrape a website as soon as it is updated?

Tags: r, web-scraping, automation, tidyverse, rvest

Every day around 11:30-12:30 the Swiss government posts new corona statistics. I need a push message on my phone as soon as the website is updated.

My script works if I run it after the site is updated. But when I schedule it on my raspberry pi nothing ever happens. It might be that the government website kicks me out after a certain number of connections but I don't know that. Also, it's hard to try because the website only updates once a day. Any suggestions on what I can do here?

```
if (!require('tidyverse')) {install.packages('tidyverse')};library('tidyverse')
if (!require('rvest')) {install.packages('rvest')};library('rvest')
if (!require('pushoverr')) {install.packages('pushoverr')};library('pushoverr')
Datum <- Sys.Date()
BAG <- xml2::read_html('https://www.bag.admin.ch/bag/de/home/krankheiten/ausbrueche-epidemien-pandemien/aktuelle-ausbrueche-epidemien/novel-cov/situation-schweiz-und-international.html')
Tabelle_BAG <- BAG %>% html_nodes('#2030838475+ .mod-table th') %>% html_text()
Datum_BAG_Zeit <- Tabelle_BAG[1] 
Datum_BAG_Zeit <- lubridate::dmy_h(Datum_BAG_Zeit)
Datum_BAG <- lubridate::date(Datum_BAG_Zeit)
while (Datum != Datum_BAG) {
  BAG_loop <- xml2::read_html('https://www.bag.admin.ch/bag/de/home/krankheiten/ausbrueche-epidemien-pandemien/aktuelle-ausbrueche-epidemien/novel-cov/situation-schweiz-und-international.html')
  Tabelle_BAG <- BAG %>% html_nodes('#2030838475+ .mod-table th') %>% html_text()
  Datum_BAG_Zeit <- Tabelle_BAG[1] 
  Datum_BAG_Zeit <- lubridate::dmy_h(Datum_BAG_Zeit)
  Datum_BAG <- lubridate::date(Datum_BAG_Zeit)
  print('nope')
  Sys.sleep(5)
  }
Anzahl_Faelle <- BAG %>% html_nodes('#2030838475+ .mod-table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2)') %>% html_text()
text <- paste0('**Test** BAG meldet ', Anzahl_Faelle, ' Infektionen')
set_pushover_app(token='xxx')
pushover(message = text, user='xxx')
quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess:

The problem might be the web server or the firewall.

If I were the System Administrator of that website I would not allow unlimited TCP connection requests arriving from the same IP client address.

Build a script, or find one on-line, that once every 10 minutes requests the page you are interested in and see what happens.

Ciao,
Enrico Migliore